# EF Core pass JsonPath parameters to Postrges SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 7.0 with Postgresql 14.0.
In my DataBase I have schema "dbo" with "issues" table. The "issues" entity has int Id.

For example, if I pass parameters like :

```
jsonPath = "$.a";
compareOption = ">=";
filterValue = "100";
```

to the following method:

```
public async Task GetIssuesFromJsonpathFilter(string jsonPath, string compareOption, string filterValue)
{
    var sql =
        $"select id from (select id, jsonb_path_query(jsondata, '{jsonPath} ? (@ {compareOption} {filterValue})') from dbo.issues) as query_result";
    var issueIds = await _context.Database
        .SqlQueryRaw<int>(sql)
        .ToListAsync(ct);

    // Other code...
}
```

And it works just fine. In the first query I'm getting filtered by jsonb entities ids and then get the entities.
But there's possibility for injections, and I want to disable them.

I tried this one:

```
var issueIds = await _context.Database
        .SqlQuery<int>(
            $"select id from (select id, jsonb_path_query(jsondata, '{jsonPath} ? (@ {compareOption} {filterValue})') from dbo.issues) as query_result")
        .ToListAsync(ct);
```

but getting exception about

```
"error": "42601: ERROR: syntax error at string jsonpath (: \" \")\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 55"
```

How should I solve this?
And also, the value of filterValue can either be "123" for integers searches, and ""123"" for strings searches.

```
jsonPath = "$.a";
compareOption = "==";
filterValue = "\"qwe\"";
```